# What is the direction of current flow in myelinated nerve cells?

Tags: neuroscience, homework, electrophysiology

Is it correct to say electric current flows through the extracellular space, or cytosol of a nerve fiber during impulse conduction?

I know that an impulse is actually a change of membrane potential which is transferred along the length of a neuron through transfer of ions (by a series of ion channels and pumps).

In myelinated axons our professor told us the following:

> When a nerve impulse propagates along a myelinated axon an electric
>   current (carried by ions) flows through the extracellular fluid
>   surrounding  the myelin sheath and through the cytosol from one node
>   to the next.

**How exactly does the current flow in myelineated nerve fibers?**

Comment: @Christiaan It answered my question to some extent but I have a query, I have already posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During an action potential current flows across the neuronal membrane. Basically, during depolarization, Na<sup>+</sup> goes into the cell, during repolarization K<sup>+</sup> goes out. This process for a myelinated axon is shown in Fig. 1.

Action potentials in myelinated neurons jump from node to node, a process called **[saltatory nerve conduction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10921/)**. These nodes, called **[nodes of Ranvier](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v4/n12/fig_tab/nrn1253_F1.html)**, lack myelin and contain Na<sup>+</sup> and K<sup>+</sup> channels. Outside these nodes there is insulating myelin wrapped around the axon and the axonal membrane lacks Na<sup>+</sup> and K<sup>+</sup> channels there.

What happens during an action potential at a node is the following: Na<sup>+</sup> rushes in at the node. Because of the insulating myelin in the next axonal segment leading up to the next node in line, Na<sup>+</sup> can run through the axon to the next node **without much signal loss**. This **[passive spread](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/courses/1010/mangels/neuro/neurosignaling/neurosignaling.html)** of depolarizing **current** is much faster than repeatedly generate a new action potential along the length of the axon.

To answer your questions now:

> *Question*: Is it correct to say electric current flows through the extracellular space or cytosol of a nerve during impulse conduction?

***Answer***: **Yes**... and no. No, because electric current and notably Na<sup>+</sup> and K<sup>+</sup> flow *perpendicular* to the axonal membrane during action potentials. Yes, because the Na<sup>+</sup> ions do move through passive current spread through the axon to the next node.

> *Question*: How exactly does the current flow in myelineated nerve fibers?

***Answer***: Your professor was spot on. During depolarization, ions (notably Na<sup>+</sup> in this case) are carried from the extracellular space through Na<sup>+</sup> channels in the node of Ranvier to the intracellular space. From there it spreads through passive diffusion to then next node.

[image: AP]
<sup>Fig. 1. Action potential generation in myelinated axons. source: [Purves *et al*.(2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10921/)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Purves *et al*. (ed). *Neuroscience*. 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. Sunderland (MA): Sinauer Associates (2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10921/)</sub>